# Cant find the source to a specific image in an app using xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have tried for the last 4 days to find an illusive image in that app, I am new to xamarin forms and a client asked me to replace an image which I did, but I have left with another image that I should implement and I can't find its source, the XML code for the specific section looks like this.

```
           <ScrollView Grid.Row="2"
                    HeightRequest="50"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    IsVisible="{Binding PhotosVisible.Value}"
                    x:Name="ScrollPhotos">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                         Spacing="0"
                         VerticalOptions="Center"
                         Padding="5,0"
                         x:Name="StackPhotos">
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

and the place I'm trying to implement the photo in is:

should be an image instead of the blank grey rectengle

[image: 1]

(should be an image instead of the blank grey rectangle)

I cant find the source to the other image, and I even deleted something that was pretty similar in the drawAble folder but it changed nothing.

any help or suggestion will be helpful, Thanks. :)

edit:
The xml.cs source code:

```
 [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class DashboardPage : ExtPage
    {
        public DashboardPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, MashamAppForms.Helpers.Settings.NativeSetting.BottonPadding);

            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing() {
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Application>(App.Current, "DashboardFillDates", FillDates);
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Application, CPhoto[]>(App.Current, "DashboardFillPhotos", FillPhotos);
            base.OnAppearing();
        }

        protected override void OnDisappearing() {
            MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<Application>(App.Current, "DashboardFillDates");
            base.OnDisappearing();
        }

        void FillPhotos(Application arg1, CPhoto[] arg2) {
            var bc = (DashboardViewModel)BindingContext;

            StackPhotos.Children.Clear();
            if (arg2 == null)
                return;
            foreach (var photo in arg2) {
                var image = new CachedImage {
                    Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill,
                    Source = photo.Path,
                    BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#504F77AB"),
                    DownsampleHeight = 100,
                    HeightRequest = 40,
                    WidthRequest = 60,
                    Margin = new Thickness(5, 0)
                };
                Commands.SetTap(image, bc.ViewImageCommand);
                Commands.SetTapParameter(image, photo);

                StackPhotos.Children.Add(image);
            }

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                try {
                    ScrollPhotos.ScrollToAsync(StackPhotos.Children.LastOrDefault(), ScrollToPosition.End, false);
                }
                catch {

                }
            });
        }


        void FillDates(Application application) {
            var bc = (DashboardViewModel)BindingContext;
            var dates = bc.Dates;

            StackDates.Children.Clear();

            if (dates == null)
                return;

            for (var i = 0; i < dates.Length; i++) {
                var t = dates[i];
                var grid = new Grid {
                    RowDefinitions =
                    {
                            new RowDefinition {Height = GridLength.Star},
                            new RowDefinition {Height = GridLength.Star},
                            new RowDefinition {Height = GridLength.Star}
                        },
                    Padding = new Thickness(5, 0),
                    RowSpacing = 0,
                    BindingContext = t
                };

                grid.SetBinding(Grid.BackgroundColorProperty, "BackgroundColor.Value");

                var l1 = new Label {
                    Text = t.HebrewDay,
                    TextColor = t.TextColor,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label))
                };
                l1.SetBinding(Label.TextColorProperty, "TextColor.Value");
                grid.Children.Add(l1, 0, 0);

                var l2 = new Label {
                    Text = t.HebrewDate,
                    TextColor = t.TextColor,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label))
                };
                l2.SetBinding(Label.TextColorProperty, "TextColor.Value");
                grid.Children.Add(l2, 0, 1);

                var l3 = new Label {
                    Text = t.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                    TextColor = t.TextColor,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label))
                };
                l3.SetBinding(Label.TextColorProperty, "TextColor.Value");
                grid.Children.Add(l3, 0, 2);

                var gest = new TapGestureRecognizer {
                    Command = bc.ChangeDateCommand,
                    CommandParameter = t
                };

                grid.GestureRecognizers.Add(gest);

                StackDates.Children.Add(grid);

                if (i != dates.Length - 1)
                    StackDates.Children.Add(new BoxView {
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
                        WidthRequest = 1,
                        Color = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["SelectionColor"]
                    });
            }

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                try {
                    ScrollDates.ScrollToAsync(StackDates.Children.LastOrDefault(), ScrollToPosition.End, false);
                }
                catch {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

and the viewModel.cs is:

```
 public class DashboardViewModel : FormsBaseViewModel
    {
        static bool _nowAsking;

        static bool _scanning;

        public ICommand ChangeDateCommand { get; }

        public ICommand LogoutCommand { get; }

        public ICommand ListHeaderCommand { get; }

        public ICommand EventCommand { get; }

        public ICommand QrCommand { get; }

        public ICommand ViewImageCommand { get; }

        public ICommand PhotoCommand { get; }

        public ICommand FeedbackCommand { get; }

        public ICommand LocationCommand { get; }

        public ICommand ContactsCommand { get; }

        public ICommand MessagesCommand { get; }

        public ICommand FileCommand { get; }

        public ObservableProperty<int> CarouselPosition { get; }
        
        public ObservableProperty<BasePageState> EventsState { get; } = new ObservableProperty<BasePageState>();

        public ObservableProperty<bool> IsBusy { get; } = new ObservableProperty<bool>();

        public ObservableProperty<bool> PhotosVisible { get; } = new ObservableProperty<bool>();

        public SmartCollection<EventDetails> EventList { get; set; }

        public Conferance Conferance { get; set; }

        public bool SubtitleVisible => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Conferance?.SubTitle);

        public string Phone { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string RealId { get; set; }

        public EventDetails[] Events { get; set; }

        public QrDetails[] QrDetails { get; set; }

        public CPhoto[] CPhotos { get; set; }

        public string FileLink { get; set; }

        public string Greeting { get; set; }

        public string ApiKey { get; set; }

        public CParticipant[] Participants { get; set; }

        public ThreeDatesItem[] Dates { get; set; }

        private ThreeDatesItem _selected;

        public ThreeDatesItem SelectedDate
        {
            get => _selected;
            set
            {
                _selected = value;

                EventList.Clear();
                Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    await Task.Delay(100);
                    EventList.AddRange(GetEvents(value.Date));
                });
            }
        }

        public DashboardViewModel()
        {
            CarouselPosition = new ObservableProperty<int>();
            EventList = new SmartCollection<EventDetails>();
            ChangeDateCommand = new Command<ThreeDatesItem>(item =>
            {
                foreach (var tdi in Dates)
                {
                    tdi.IsSelected = false;
                }
                item.IsSelected = true;
                SelectedDate = item;
            });
            LogoutCommand = new Command(async () =>
            {
                Settings.Authed = false;
                Settings.SavedPhone = "";
                Settings.SavedId = "";
                OneSignal.Current.DeleteTag("confId");
                await NavigationService.Navigate<LoginViewModel>();
                NavigationService.ClearNavigationStack();
            });
            ListHeaderCommand = new Command<EventDetails>(details =>
            {
                var mainColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["SelectionColor"];

                if (details.IsOpened)
                {
                    var del = EventList.Where(e => e.WhatMashov == details.IsMashov).ToArray();
                    for (var i = 0; i < del.Length; i++)
                    {
                        EventList.Remove(del[i]);
                    }
                    details.SeparatorColor.Value = mainColor;
                }
                else
                {
                    var add = Events?.Where(e => e.Day == details.Day && e.WhatMashov == details.IsMashov).ToArray();
                    details.SeparatorColor.Value = add.Length == 0? mainColor : Color.LightGray;

                    var after = details;
                    for (var i = 0; i < add.Length; i++)
                    {
                        add[i].SeparatorColor.Value = i == add.Length - 1 ? mainColor : Color.LightGray;
                        add[i].GridPadding = new Thickness(10, 10, 20, 10);

                        EventList.Insert(EventList.IndexOf(after) + 1, add[i]);
                        after = add[i];
                    }
                }

                EventList.Last().SeparatorColor.Value = Color.Transparent;

                details.IsOpened = !details.IsOpened;
            });
            EventCommand = new Command<EventDetails>(async details =>
            {
                await NavigationService.Navigate<EventInfoViewModel>(model =>
                {
                    model.Participants.AddRange(Participants?.Where(e => e.EventId == details.EventId));
                    model.Date.Value = SelectedDate;
                    model.EventDetails.Value = details;
                    model.Phone = Phone;
                    model.IsVisibleDescription.Value = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(details.Description);
                    model.IsVisibleLecturers.Value = model.Participants.Count > 0;
                    model.Conferance = Conferance;
                    model.AllEvents = Events;
                    model.Name = Name;
                    model.SelectedEventDetails = details;
                    model.QrDetails = QrDetails;
                });
            });
            QrCommand = new Command<EventDetails>(details =>
            {
                if (details.QrState == QrState.Normal)
                    NavigationService.Navigate<QrPickerViewModel>(NavigationType.Popup, m => {
                        m.EventDetails = Events;
                        m.EventId = details.EventId;
                        m.QrDetails = QrDetails;
                        m.Phone = Phone;
                        m.Name = Name;
                        m.ConfId = Conferance.Id;
                    });
            });
            ViewImageCommand = new Command<CPhoto>(p =>
            {
                var s = p?.Path?.Trim();

                var photos = CPhotos.Select(e => new MyPhoto {
                    URL = e?.Path?.Trim(),
                    Title = string.Empty,
                    Link = e?.SponsorLink?.Trim()
                }).ToList();

                if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
                    photos.Reverse();

                var pos = photos?.FindIndex(e => e.URL == s) ?? 0;

                var config = new PhotoConfig {
                    Photos = photos,
                    StartIndex = pos,
                    ActionButtonPressed = async (index) => {
                        var action = await AlertCenter.ActionSheet(Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android ? Localization.SelectAction : null, Localization.Cancel, null, Localization.SponsorLink);
                        if (action == Localization.SponsorLink) {
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(photos[index]?.Link)) {
                                AlertCenter.Error(Localization.NoLink);
                            }
                            else {
                                Device.OpenUri(new Uri(photos[index].Link, UriKind.Absolute));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };

                config.Show();
            });
            PhotoCommand = new Command(async () =>
            {
                await LoadingPopupService.Show();

                var photos = await SimpleServerRequest.Request<CPhoto[]>(new Uri("http://app.masham.org.il/insertToConfearnce2.php?Action=getAllEvents&TableName=I_" + Conferance.Id));

                await LoadingPopupService.Close();

                if (photos.Item1)
                    await NavigationService.Navigate<PhotoGalleryViewModel>(m =>
                    {
                        m.Photos.Value = photos.Item2.Where(e => e.Type == "גלריה").ToArray();
                        m.ConfId = Conferance.Id;
                        m.ApiKey = ApiKey;
                    });
                else
                    AlertCenter.Error(Localization.ErrorLoading);
                
            });
            FeedbackCommand = new Command(async () =>
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Conferance?.SurvayLink))
                {
                    AlertCenter.Error(Localization.NoLink);
                    return;
                }
                
                await LoadingPopupService.Show();

                var res = await SimpleServerRequest.Request(new Uri($@"http://app.masham.org.il/insertToConfearnce2.php?Action=getServerDateAndtime&CID={Conferance.Id}"));

                await LoadingPopupService.Close();

                try
                {
                    if (res.Success)
                    {
                        if (res.Result.ToLower() == "true")
                            Device.OpenUri(new Uri(Conferance?.SurvayLink, UriKind.Absolute));
                        else 
                            AlertCenter.Error(Localization.NoMashovTime);
                    }
                    else
                        AlertCenter.Error(Localization.ErrorLoading);
                }
                catch
                {
                    AlertCenter.Error(Localization.IncorrectLink);
                }
            });
            LocationCommand = new Command(() =>
            {
                Device.OpenUri(new Uri("https://waze.com/ul?q=" + Conferance?.NameOfLocation));
            });
            ContactsCommand = new Command(async () =>
            {
                await NavigationService.Navigate<ContactsViewModel>(m =>
                {
                    m.Phone.Value = Conferance?.Phone;
                    m.Location.Value = Conferance?.NameOfLocation;
                    m.Email.Value = Conferance?.Email;
                });
            });
            MessagesCommand = new Command(async () =>
            {
                await LoadingPopupService.Show();

                var messages = await SimpleServerRequest.Request<CMessage[]>(new Uri(
                    "http://app.masham.org.il/insertToConfearnce2.php?Action=getAllEvents&TableName=" +
                    "Messages_" + Conferance.Id));

                await LoadingPopupService.Close();

                if (messages.Item1)
                {
                    DependencyService.Get<ILocalSettings>().PushCounter = 0;
                    await NavigationService.Navigate<MessagesViewModel>(m =>
                    {
                        m.Messages.AddRange(messages.Item2 ?? new CMessage[0]);
                        m.ConfId = Conferance.Id.ToString();
                    });
                }
                else
                    AlertCenter.Error(Localization.ErrorLoading);
            });

            FileCommand = new Command(() => {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileLink)) {
                    AlertCenter.Error(Localization.NoLink);
                    return;
                }
                Device.OpenUri(new Uri(FileLink, UriKind.Absolute));
            });
        }

        public async void Resumed() {
            {
                if (_nowAsking)
                    return;
                _nowAsking = true;

                if (NavigationService.CurrentModalPage == null && NavigationService.CurrentPage.GetType() == typeof(DashboardPage) && !LoadingPopupService.IsLoading) {
                    IsBusy.Value = true;
                    await LoadingPopupService.Show();

                    var users = await SimpleServerRequest.Request<UserAndConferance[]>(new Uri($"http://app.masham.org.il/apimasham.php?Action=getUser&idUsername={Phone}&realId={RealId}"));
                    if (users.Item1) {
                        var user = users.Item2.FirstOrDefault();
                        ApiKey = user?.ApiKey;
                        var conf = users.Item2.Select(e => e.Conferance).FirstOrDefault(e => e != null && e.Id == Conferance.Id);

                        if (conf == null) {
                            _nowAsking = false;
                            IsBusy.Value = false;

                            Settings.Authed = false;
                            Settings.SavedPhone = "";
                            Settings.SavedId = "";
                            await LoadingPopupService.Close();
                            await AlertCenter.ErrorAsync(Localization.ConfNotFound);
                            await NavigationService.Navigate<LoginViewModel>();
                            NavigationService.ClearNavigationStack();

                            return;
                        }

                        var eventContainer = await SimpleServerRequest.Request<EventContainer>(new Uri($"http://app.masham.org.il/apimasham.php?Action=getEvents&confId={Conferance.Id}&phone={Phone}"));

                        if (eventContainer.Item1 && eventContainer.Item2 != null) {
                            var dates = eventContainer.Item2.EventDetails
                                ?.Select(e => new {
                                    e.Day,
                                    e.HebrewDay
                                })
                                .Distinct()
                                .Select(e => new ThreeDatesItem {
                                    Date = e.Day,
                                    HebrewDate = e.HebrewDay
                                })
                                .OrderByDescending(e => e.Date)
                                .ToArray();
                            
                            Events = eventContainer.Item2.EventDetails ?? new EventDetails[0];
                            QrDetails = eventContainer.Item2.QrDetails ?? new QrDetails[0];

                            QrStateHelper.SetQrStatesForAll(Events, QrDetails, eventContainer.Item2.QrAnswers);

                            if (conf.Type == "קורס" && dates != null) {
                                var p = 1;
                                for (var i = dates.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                                    dates[i].HebrewDate = "מפגש " + p++;
                                }
                            }

                            var isEqualDates = Dates != null && Dates.Length == dates?.Length && conf.Type == Conferance.Type;
                            if (isEqualDates)
                                for (var i = 0; i < dates.Length; i++) {
                                    isEqualDates = dates[i].Date == Dates[i].Date;
                                    if (!isEqualDates)
                                        break;
                                }

                            if (!isEqualDates)
                                Dates = dates;

                            var photos = eventContainer.Item2.Photos?.Where(e => e.Type == "קרוסלה").ToArray();

                            var isEqualPhotos = CPhotos != null && CPhotos.Length == photos?.Length;
                            if (isEqualPhotos)
                                for (var i = 0; i < photos.Length; i++) {
                                    isEqualPhotos = photos[i].Path == CPhotos[i].Path;
                                    if (!isEqualPhotos)
                                        break;
                                }
                            else
                                CPhotos = photos;

                            Conferance = conf;

                            FileLink = eventContainer.Item2.Photos?.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Type == "קובץ")?.Path;

                            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Conferance));

                            PrepareDatesAndPhotos(!isEqualDates, !isEqualPhotos);

                            if (Events.Length > 0) {
                                EventsState.Value = BasePageState.Normal;
                            }
                            else {
                                EventList.Clear();
                                EventsState.Value = BasePageState.NoData;
                            }

                            _nowAsking = false;
                            IsBusy.Value = false;
                            await LoadingPopupService.Close();

                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    IsBusy.Value = false;
                    await LoadingPopupService.Close();
                    await AlertCenter.ErrorAsync(Localization.ErrorLoading);
                }
                _nowAsking = false;
            }
        }

        public override async void FirstAppearing()
        {
            base.FirstAppearing();
            NavigationService.ClearNavigationStack();

            await Task.Delay(300);

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                PrepareDatesAndPhotos();
            });
        }

        void PrepareDatesAndPhotos(bool updDates = true, bool updPhotos = true) {
            if (updPhotos)
                MessagingCenter.Send(App.Current, "DashboardFillPhotos", CPhotos);

            PhotosVisible.Value = CPhotos?.Any() ?? false;

            if (Dates?.Any() ?? false) {
                if (updDates) {
                    var today = Dates.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Date == DateTime.Today);
                    if (today != null) {
                        today.IsSelected = true;
                        SelectedDate = today;
                    }
                    else {
                        var date = Dates[Dates.Length - 1];
                        date.IsSelected = true;
                        SelectedDate = date;
                    } 
                    MessagingCenter.Send(App.Current, "DashboardFillDates");
                }
                else {
                    SelectedDate = SelectedDate;
                }
            }
        }

        private EventDetails[] GetEvents(DateTime date)
        {
            var items = Events?.Where(e => e.Day == date && e.WhatMashov == "").OrderBy(e => e.StartTime).ToArray();

            var mainColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["SelectionColor"];

            if (items?.Length > 0)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
                {
                    items[i].IsOpened = false;
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(items[i].IsMashov) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(items[i].WhatMashov))
                    {
                        items[i].SeparatorColor.Value = mainColor;
                        items[i].GridPadding = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        items[i].GridPadding = new Thickness(10, 10, 20, 10);

                        if (i != items.Length - 1)
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(items[i + 1].IsMashov) ||
                                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(items[i + 1].WhatMashov))
                            {
                                items[i].SeparatorColor.Value = Color.LightGray;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                items[i].SeparatorColor.Value = mainColor;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                items.Last().SeparatorColor.Value = Color.Transparent;
            }

            return items;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try checking how is the second image added. I guess both the images are added to StackPhotos. So please check how/what are the images are added to StackPhotos in your code.

Comment: i guess i dosent know how to work with the StackPhotos thing,  all I get a class without any links or embedded photos

Comment: StackPhotos is the name of the stacklayout, you might have used it in your codebehind class. Check the respective xaml.cs file for its reference

Comment: Also please post your xaml and its respective .cs file(codebehind file). To understand the issue better

Comment: `StackPhotos.Children.Add(image);` is the line where your images are added to the layout. Try Debugging the code  `Source = photo.Path,`  to check the image path.